# Возвращает пустую строку,

Tags: java

Возвращает пустую строку. Помогите найти ошибку.

```
String binaryNumber = "100111010000";
    System.out.println("Двоичное число " + binaryNumber + " равно шестнадцатеричному числу " + 
toHex(binaryNumber));

public static String toHex(String binaryNumber) {
    String hexNumber = "";
    if (binaryNumber == "" || binaryNumber == null) {
        return hexNumber;
    }
    String number = "";
    int size = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < binaryNumber.length(); i++) {
        if ((binaryNumber.length() % 4) != 0) {
                binaryNumber = "0" + binaryNumber;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < binaryNumber.length(); i += size) {
        number = binaryNumber.substring(i, i+size);
        switch (number) {
            case "0000" -> hexNumber = String.valueOf(0);
            case "0001" -> hexNumber = String.valueOf(1);
            case "0010" -> hexNumber = String.valueOf(2);
            case "0011" -> hexNumber = String.valueOf(3);
            case "0100" -> hexNumber = String.valueOf(4);
            case "0101" -> hexNumber = String.valueOf(5);
            case "0110" -> hexNumber = String.valueOf(6);
            case "0111" -> hexNumber = String.valueOf(7);
            case "1000" -> hexNumber = String.valueOf(8);
            case "1001" -> hexNumber = String.valueOf(9);
            case "1010" -> hexNumber = String.valueOf('A');
            case "1011" -> hexNumber = String.valueOf('B');
            case "1100" -> hexNumber = String.valueOf('C');
            case "1101" -> hexNumber = String.valueOf('D');
            case "1110" -> hexNumber = String.valueOf('E');
        }
    }
    return hexNumber;
}
```

Comment: Отладчиком пройдитесь

Comment: Где `'F'`? `switch`/`case`  без `break` работает не так как вы ожидаете. Отладчик - ваш надежный друг и помощник в изучении языка программирования!

Comment: Представленный код НЕ возвращает пустую строку.  Он возвращает последнюю цифру hex-числа, так как в `hexNumber` не накапливается значение (следовало использовать `+=` вместо `=`).  Пустая строка может быть возвращена для числа, содержащего одни `F`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как было указано в комментариях, представленный код НЕ возвращает пустую строку при вызове `toHex("100111010000")` -- будет возвращено строковое значение `"0"` вместо ожидаемого `"9D0"`, так как не выполняется "накапливание" результата в переменной `hexNumber` в операторе `switch`.

Также, отсутствует `case` для значения `"1111"`, соответствующего `0xF`, соответственно переменная `hexNumber` останется неизменной при обнаружении такого значения.

Простое "решение" -- убрать массовую копипасту из операторов `case`, использовав `switch-expression`, для этого придётся добавить обработку случая `"1111"` и выбрасывание исключения для любого другого варианта входной строки.

Тогда основной цикл в методе `toHex` будет выглядеть так:

```java
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < binaryNumber.length(); i += size) {
    number = binaryNumber.substring(i, i + size);
    hexNumber += switch (number) {
        case "0000" -> String.valueOf(0);
        case "0001" -> String.valueOf(1);
        case "0010" -> String.valueOf(2);
        case "0011" -> String.valueOf(3);
        case "0100" -> String.valueOf(4);
        case "0101" -> String.valueOf(5);
        case "0110" -> String.valueOf(6);
        case "0111" -> String.valueOf(7);
        case "1000" -> String.valueOf(8);
        case "1001" -> String.valueOf(9);
        case "1010" -> String.valueOf('A');
        case "1011" -> String.valueOf('B');
        case "1100" -> String.valueOf('C');
        case "1101" -> String.valueOf('D');
        case "1110" -> String.valueOf('E');
        case "1111" -> String.valueOf('F');
        default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad binary number: " + number);
    };
}
return hexNumber;
// ...
```

---

Однако оставшаяся реализация имеет другие недостатки:

- неэффективное использование строковой конкатенации в цикле -- следует заменить на `StringBuilder`, размер которого не превысит `input.length() / 4 + 1`
- для *очень* длинной входной строки (длиной `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2` и выше) попытка добавить несколько ведущих нулей, чтобы сделать длину строки кратной четырём, приведёт к исключению -- следует сначала обработать префикс, ширина которого варьируется от 1 до 4 символов, а затем у оставшейся строки брать по 4 символа.
- многословный оператор `switch` на 16 + 1 `case` можно заменить на обращение к шестнадцатиричному алфавиту (например в виде строки `"0123456789ABCDEF"`) по индексу, который легко получить при помощи [`Integer::valueOf(String str, int radix)`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java8/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-int-)

Получившееся решение может выглядеть так:

```java
private static final String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";

public static String toHex(String binaryNumber) {
    if (null == binaryNumber || binaryNumber.isEmpty()) {
        return binaryNumber;
    }

    int len = binaryNumber.length();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(len / 4 + 1);
    int size = len % 4 == 0 ? 4 : len % 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; size = 4) {
        String num = binaryNumber.substring(i, i += size);
        result.append(HEX.charAt(Integer.valueOf(num, 2)));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```